# How to activate Add to Home screen in chrome mobile 31?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I try to use Add Do Home menu in chrome Mobile. M31 but it is allways hidden even when it is  activated in chrome://flags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been disabled for now because it doesn't work in the current Chrome Beta for Android: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=316311

Comment: @miracle2k not on my Samsung S4 with Chrome 31.0.1650.59 :-(